# Getting random post from rss feed

Tags: php, rss

I have an rss feed, created by Yahoo Pipes and I need to get random post from it. How is it possible to realize this on php?

Answer (score 1):

Read the feed using [XML Parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) and put it in an array. then, use array_rand to pick a random item from the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
function load_xml_feed($feed)
{
global $RanVal;
$i= 1;
$FeedXml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
foreach ($FeedXml->channel->item as $topic) {
$title[$i] = (string)$topic->title;
$link[$i] = (string)$topic->link;
$description[$i] = (string)$topic->description;
$i++;
}
$randtopic = rand(2, $i);
$link = trim($link[$randtopic]);
$title = trim($title[$randtopic]);
$description = trim($description[$randtopic]);
$RanVal = array($title,$link,$description);
return $RanVal;
}
$rss = "http://www.sabaharabi.com/rss/rss.xml";
load_xml_feed($rss);
$link = $RanVal[1];
$title = $RanVal[0];
$description = $RanVal[2];
echo "<h1>".$title."</h1><h2>".$link."</h2><p>".$description."</p>";
```